# LazyLoad in routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use LazyLoad but does not load the controllers

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/', { 
                templateUrl : 'pages/calendar/week/page.html',
        controller:'MainCtrl',
         resolve: {
        lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
          return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
            name: 'app',
            files: [
              '/pages/calendar/week/controller.js',
            ]
          }]);
        }]
      }
            })
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you add your controller definition? No error in console? Is your "app" module well defined?

Answer (score 0):

I use lazyloading too, but without the name/file param :

```
 var interfaceApp = angular.module('interfaceApp', [ 'ngRoute','oc.lazyLoad' ]);
 interfaceApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider.
           when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/home/home.html',
              controller: 'homeController',
              resolve: {
                 lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({files: ['js/controllers/homeController.js']});
                 }]
              }
           }).

           otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/'
           });
    }]);
```

Comment: don't forget to inject 'oc.lazyLoad' in the module

Comment: this is not working for me. I am using "angular.module('interfaceApp').controller(...)"

Answer (score 0):

you need to change to `angular.module('interfaceApp').controller(...)` if you are defining your controller as `interfaceApp.controller(...)`